# Limiting a querset for a field in Django-Filter

Tags: python, django, django-filter

I have a django-filter `FilterSet` that takes a queryset of a user's saved links. Tags is a `ManyToManyField`, and I'd like to narrow that selection down to tags created (owned) by the same user. Completely at a loss - the docs aren't that extensive.

```
class LinkFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):

    class Meta:
        model = Link
        fields = ['title', 'domain', 'tags', 'date', 'modified']
```

https://github.com/alex/django-filter/

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used django-filter before, but looking at the docs you should be able to do something like below. You'll need to pass the user you want to filter on in the constructor for LinkFilter for the keyword argument `user`. Otherwise it will continue to show all tags from all users. I also guessed that the User ForeignKey property on the Link class was named `created_by`.

```
class LinkFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Link
        fields = ['title', 'domain', 'tags', 'date', 'modified']

    def __init__(self, data=None, queryset=None, prefix=None, strict=None, user=None):
        super(LinkFilter, self).__init__(data=data, queryset=queryset, prefix=prefix, strict=strict))
        if user:
            self.filters['tags'].filter(created_by=user)
```

Comment: Hmm. I much prefer this method as it would allow me to use the user in other fields, but I'm getting a type error when I reload the page:

    __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'user'

Comment: I'm passing in the user to the LinkFilter like this: LinkFilter(self.request.GET, queryset=qs, user=self.request.user)

Comment: Sorry, that's my fault. I've changed the code so it's not as lazy.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help so far. Unfortunately that seems to have introduced another problem, although it looks like the user object is now being correctly passed to the LinkFilter. It's now complaining that 'filter gets an unexpected keyword argument', which is the created_by bit down at the bottom.

Comment: Are you passing it in the ```super()``` call? If so, don't.

Comment: Nope. It's something to do with the ['tags'].filter() bit.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how i did it for a very similar situation (tried to adapt to your case) :

```
class LinkFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        current_user = kwargs['current_user']
        del kwargs['current_user']
        super(LinkFilter, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.filters['customer'].extra.update(
            {'queryset': models.Tags.objects.get_my_tags(current_user)})

    class Meta:
        model = Link
        fields = ['title', 'domain', 'tags', 'date', 'modified']
```

in your view :

```
def home(request):
    f = LinkFilter(request.GET, queryset=models.Links.objects.get_my_links(request.user), current_user=request.user)
    return render_to_response('public/links.html', {'filter': f})
```

with `get_my_tags` and `get_my_links` defined in my `managers.py` file.

Answer (score 1):

Just need to override the property form method, and then customize your uqeryset based on your conditions

```
class LinkFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):

@property
def form(self):
    form = super(LinkFilter, self).form
    form.fields['yourField'].queryset = form.fields['yourField'].queryset.filter(yourFilterCondition)

    return form

class Meta:
    model=Link
    fields='__all__'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class ProductFilter(FilterSet):
    def __init__(self,data=None, queryset=None, prefix=None, strict=None, **kwargs):
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        super(ProductFilter, self).__init__(data, queryset, prefix, strict)

    @property
    def form(self):
        form = super(ProductFilter, self).form

        for key, queryset in self.kwargs.iteritems():
            form.fields[key].queryset = queryset

        return form

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['name', 'tags']

class ViewFilter(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'frontend/view_filter.html'
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ViewFilter, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        context['filter'] = ProductFilter(self.request.GET,
                                          queryset=Product.objects.filter(tags__user_id=2),
                                          tags=Tag.objects.filter(user_id=2))

        return context
```